# How to proof that for all n $ (\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 $

Tags: induction

What i had so far was this:
claim: How to proof that for all n $$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 $$

Proof

To proof:  How to proof that for all n $$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 $$

basis $n=1$:

$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3\\
(1)^2 = (1^3)\\
1 = 1$$

Induction $n = k$:
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^k i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k i^3 $$
My assumption is that this is true

$n = k+1$:
$$ \left(\sum_{i=1}^k+1 i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k+1 i^3\\
\left(\sum_{i=1}^k i +(k+1)\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k i^3 +(k+1)^3 $$

I got stuck here and i dont know how to continue.

Comment: can you use the explicit formulas for the given sums?

Comment: This has been discussed at MSE several times. Did you have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080575/proof-that-sum-of-first-n-cubes-is-always-a-perfect-square) and the related questions to it?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that but i guess so @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Its not a duplicate

Comment: @bassie $$1^3+2^3+ \cdots + n^3 = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ so it is indeed a duplicate and I suggest taking a look at the answers provided there.

Comment: You do realize that forcing the equal signs to be outside of the dollar signs makes it hard to read and confusing? Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k i^3=\frac{1}{4} k^2 (k+1)^2;\;\sum _{i=1}^k i=\frac{1}{2} k (k+1)$$

Comment: How did you come to this equation from my equation

Comment: @bassie The other answerer has proved the formulae