# Induction of the summation equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have been on this problem and my professor has given me anything useful to work with.
$$\forall n\geq 1 :\quad \sum_{i=1}^{2n} i^3 = n^2(2n+1)^2$$

This is all the work I have currently on this problem.

Base case n = 1
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n} i^3 = 1^3+2^3 = 9$$
$$n^2(2n+1)^2 = (1)^2(2(1)+1)^2 = 9$$
Suppose $$\sum_{i=1}^{2k} i^3 = k^2(2k+1)^2$$
Need to show $$\sum_{i=1}^{2k+2} i^3 = (k+1)^2(2(k+1)+1)^2$$
observe $$\sum_{i=1}^{2k+2} i^3 =\sum_{i=1}^{2k} i^3+(2k+1)^3+(2k+2)^3$$
Inductive Hypothesis says
$$=k^2(2k+1)^2+(2k+1)^3+(2k+2)^3$$
$$=(2k+1)^2(k^2+2k+1)+(2k+2)^3$$
$$=(2k+1)^2((k+1)^2)+2^3(k+1)^3$$
$$=(k+1)^2((2k+1)^2+(k+1)2^3)$$
$$=(k+1^2(2k+1)^2+(8k+8))$$
$$=(k+1)^2(4k^2+4k+8k+9)$$
$$=(k+1)^2(4k^2+12k+9)$$
$$=(k+1)^2(2k+3)^2$$
Been stuck here for a while and have no idea where to go...

Comment: To me it looks like you finished the proof, nothing more needed to say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof that sum of first $n$ cubes is always a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080575/proof-that-sum-of-first-n-cubes-is-always-a-perfect-square)

Comment: Just write the last line as $(k+1)^2(2(k+1)+1)^2$

Comment: excuse me while I go hang myself....